# How to use Spring HttpSecurity without formLogin

Tags: spring, authentication

I have SecurityConfig like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private AuthProviderByIP authProvider;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception 
{
    auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/public").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/private").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
}

}
```

And AuthProviderByIP like this:

```
@Component
public class AuthProviderByIP implements AuthenticationProvider {

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
// making own Authentication object
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
    return true;
}
```

}

And when I'm  trying to get /public resource it works fine
But when trying to get /private resource it just return forbidden page. 
I checked it with debug and authenticate(...) method is not even invoked.

When googling there is only HttpSecurity configuring with 
.formLogin().and().httpBasic()

But I need not formLogin right now. How to configure it without formLogin?

Comment: Have you tried adding just `.and().httpBasic()` at the end of your configuration?

Comment: It works now, but it steel reques Basic Authontication and credantials windows appear now. Method .httpBasic() means Basic type authontication.  supouse I need another type of that one

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security stores the `Authentication` object in `SecurityContextHolder`. Set it manuallly, if you don't want a form login or a Basic authentication. From the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#setting-the-securitycontextholder-contents-directly):

```
Authentication request = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password);
Authentication result = authenticationManager.authenticate(request);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(result);
```

You can disable Form-Login and Basic-Auth in the HttpSecurity configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http
    ...
    .httpBasic().disable()
    .formLogin().disable();
}
```